# detect merge criteria

Tags: tfs, merge

Consider the following scenario(in **chronological** order):

1. Bob checks out source.cs
2. Jack checks out source.cs
3. Jack checks in source.cs
4. Bob checks in source.cs

A *merge* needs to be performed, because Bob's version was **not** created from the latest version.

What criteria does `TFS 2010` use to determine whether a merge is required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bob's version will have been created from the Latest Version.

In Step 4, Bob will not have been allowed to check in source.cs until he has performed a "Get Latest". In TFS 2010, when you perform a "Get Latest" on a file with Pending Changes and there are changes to get from the server, then it will detect it as a conflict and require a resolution.

If the local change and server change are different enough, for example, Jack editing Line 10, and Bob edited Line 110, then the "Auto Merge" button will be available, as a conflict resolution. If both Jack and Bob changed Line 10, then you would have to deal with the conflict yourself and use a "Merge Tool" to decide which changes you want to keep.

This is a silly process, other modern SCM software will automerge when applicable without needing your input. But I guess it does mean you get to decide if it should be an automerge or not.

Brian Harry goes into more detail [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2011/08/31/merge-enhancements-in-tfs-11.aspx) on the improvements made in TFS 2012 that means you will spend a **lot** less time resolving conflicts.

Comment: So it decides to merge based on the content of the two files?

Comment: Based on the changes been brought down from the server versus the changes in the local workspace. TFS Stores changes as "deltas" so it only knows what parts of the file have changed.